# How can we access Facebook/Google APIs after authenticated via Federated Authentication in WSO2 Identity Server 5

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In my application I am using Federated Authentication in WSO2 Identity Server 5 to authenticate user using social networks. If the application wants to access there APIs how can we get the original tokens given by the authentication providers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity Servers authenticators have necessary token in there execution. We can save these tokens to user claims(attributes) by extending the authenticators. After that we can take out these tokens via the claims and use in our client applications.